# Controlling the number of significant digits in model file

Tags: pyomo

Is there a method in Pyomo for controlling the number of significant digits in the objective function and constraint matrix coefficients that get sent to the solver?

In my case, the form of the objective and the problem data is obtained from files or created in a program, and the resulting problem is then solved sequentially. As a result, using the round function or the decimal package only partially allows for the number of significant digits to be controlled. Ideally, some global method in Pyomo would be able to control the number of significant digits in the final model that gets sent to the solver in, say, an LP file.

Answer (score 0):

Which solver are you using. For instance IP-OPT has many settings. These two may help you:

```
tiny_step_tol                          0 <= (2.22045e-15) <  +inf      
   Tolerance for detecting numerically insignificant steps.
     If the search direction in the primal variables (x and s) is, in relative
     terms for each component, less than this value, the algorithm accepts the
     full step without line search.  If this happens repeatedly, the algorithm
     will terminate with a corresponding exit message. The default value is 10
     times machine precision.

tiny_step_y_tol                        0 <= (       0.01) <  +inf      
   Tolerance for quitting because of numerically insignificant steps.
     If the search direction in the primal variables (x and s) is, in relative
     terms for each component, repeatedly less than tiny_step_tol, and the
     step in the y variables is smaller than this threshold, the algorithm
     will terminate.
```

To play with these you need to set their new values in a `ipopt.opt` file in the working directory.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I’m using CPLEX. However, I’m really after a solver-independent solution, which is why I am hoping to use some Pyomo feature. 

If I print out a Pyomo model instance, then I can see that I have controlled the number of significant digits. The issue is there are a number of arithmetic expressions that are not evaluated, and when Pyomo generates an LP file for the solver, these expressions are then evaluated, which introduces a large number of decimal places. I could fix this by hard-coding my model generation, but this is far from ideal.